# WPF: change DataTemplate in resources from code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I change properties of some controls in DataTemplate that placed in resource from code?
I use .NET 3.5, so DataTemplate doesn't have Template property.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DataTemplateSelectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=VS.90).aspx#1)

#### --Edit--

I'm sorry I did not understand the question at first, I think the best way would be to write an extra template, that looks the way you want to modify the other one, find it and assign it
to the list control.

Here is a little [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/11/16/change-templates-dynamically-in-wpf.aspx)

Comment: I know how to retrieve DataTemplate from resource, but i don't know how to change it.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't get the question at first. What is it exactly you want to change?

Comment: I want to change the tooltip of image in DataTemplate for all items in ItemsControl.

Comment: No, I want to change current template. I don't know what exactly will be in tooltip, so I have only one predefined DataTemplate and I want to change it in one time.

Comment: What is exactly what you want to do? If you're going to have different types of content as tooltip you may need diffent datatemplates. Can you post some more information about your issue?

Comment: I have DataTemplate. I want to change Tooltip or Text or Content of some controls according to selected language. Localized strings are in xml (it's requirement, so I can't to change it on resource or LocBaml). So i need to replace text in DataTemplate by switching of language.